# How to redefine \end to be compatible with tabular environments?

Tags: tables, macros, siunitx, expansion

How do I have to redefine `\end` such that it is protected (as much as possible) in tabular environments? Is the best option to start the expansion of the command with `\relax`?

Suppose we have the following redefinition of `\end`, which is supposed to behave as similar as possible to the original definition of `\end`.

```
\def\XXX{something}
\let\origEnd\end
\def\end#1{%
   \def\tmp{#1}%
   \ifx\tmp\XXX
      \def\tmp{\origEnd{#1}}%
   \else
      \def\tmp{\origEnd{#1}}%
   \fi
   \tmp   
}
```

It works with standard `tabular` columns as well as with `siunitx` columns when using `\relax`, but fails with `siunitx` columns without `\relax` after the terminating `\\`.

**Fails:** siunitx column terminated by `\\` without `\relax`

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\XXX{something}
\let\origEnd\end
\def\end#1{%
   \def\tmp{#1}%
   \ifx\tmp\XXX
      \def\tmp{\origEnd{#1}}%
   \else
      \def\tmp{\origEnd{#1}}%
   \fi
   \tmp   
}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.3]}
  1 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 17.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.17 \end{tabular}
```

**Works:** siunitx column terminated by `\\` with `\relax`

```
\documentclass{article}
% ... preamble from above
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.3]}
  1 \\\relax % \relax added
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Works:** standard `tabular` column terminated by `\\` with/without `\relax`

```
\documentclass{article}
% ... preamble from above
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r} % standard tabular column type
  1 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**What is this good for:** In the `subfiles` package, it is necessary to set up `\end` such that it skips the next `\end{document}` without triggering any hooks. The above example is a reduced version of the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\end` is a tricky one because of tabulars, and how they are implemented to peek inside `\end{env}`.  If you look at the current definition of `\end` you'll see that it goes to some extent to make sure that after hitting `\end{env}` exactly twice with `\expandafter` you get `\endenv`.  This

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\show\end{env}
```

says

```
> \endenv=\relax.
<recently read> \endenv 
                        
<*> ...after\expandafter\expandafter\show\end{env}
                                                  
?
```

and this behaviour should remain after your redefinition. Of course for `\enddocument` (or `\endsomething` in your example) you want to do something else, but all other environments should behave normally.

I suggest you redefine `\end␣` instead of `\end` (after checking for an older version of LaTeX, if you want backwards compatibility), so that the machinery to get the amount of expansions right is already in place.  Then, inside `\end␣` you can use `\romannumeral` to keep the expansion going, and use an expandable string comparison (`\str_if_eq:nnTF`, for example) to check for the environment you want, then either return `\endenv` or do what you want with the special case.

Here's the working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% % %
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \StrIfEqTF \str_if_eq:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\expandafter\origEnd\csname end \endcsname
\@namedef{end }#1{%
  \romannumeral % keeps expansion going
  \StrIfEqTF{#1}{something}% compares #1 with the special environment
    {\subfiles@endsomething}% if so, do what you need here
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\z@\origEnd}% otherwise pretend nothing happened
  {#1}}
\def\subfiles@endsomething#1{\z@
  \typeout{Ending special environment #1.}
  ((Special end))\par%
  \origEnd{#1}}
\makeatother
% % %

\newenvironment{something}
  {special env\par}
  {end special env\par}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.3]}
  1 \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{something}
  1
\end{something}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it will take a bit to digest your answer. I already wondered about the strange way `\end` is constructed, and the purpose of `\romannumeral`.

Comment: @gernot Yeah, `\end` was a tough one.  In case you don't know, you can see the documented source for `\end` [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/9d6d680b89251e2dafaa6177d39c67e7bf4f2107/base/ltmiscen.dtx#L761), which hopefully explain things a bit.  Feel free to ask if you have questions