# Strange behaviour with tablenotes and threeparttable spacing upon updating MiKTeX: arbitrary space added depending on location

Tags: tables, spacing, subfiles

It appears that after a certain point in my (large document with a big template, working on a MWE...), additional space is added before the tablenotes. I did not notice this before, and it only occurs on my machine where I recently updated MiKTeX. When transfering the doc to another computer with not-so-up-to-date packages, the issue is not apparent. Issue occurs with pdfTeX or LuaTeX.

Any insight on what may be happening?

It appears that neither tpt or tablenotes have been updated in a while.

```
            \begin{threeparttable}[t]%
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    Hello world\\\bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}% SPACE UNEXPECTEDLY ADDED HERE
                    Note
                \end{tablenotes}%
            \end{threeparttable}%
```

EDIT:

Sometimes shows this (what I want):
[image]

But sometimes shows: [image]

Note that it varies within the same document!

EDIT 2:

I made a MWE.

Main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    \subfile{sub}
            \begin{threeparttable}%
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    Hello world outside subfile\\\bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}%
                    Note
                \end{tablenotes}%
            \end{threeparttable}%
    
\end{document}
```

Sub.tex

```
\documentclass[Main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
        \begin{threeparttable}%
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    Hello world inside subfile\\\bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}%
                    Note
                \end{tablenotes}%
            \end{threeparttable}%
\end{document}
```

Output: [image]

Comment: Could you show what's happening?

Comment: Your code fragment is not compilable because in `tablenotes` is missed `\item`. Adding it it works as expected. However, shoved result are not produced by your code fragment. SP pčease extend it to complete small document which will reproduce your problem

Comment: @Bernard please see the edit. Zarko I use [para] setting for tablenotes.

Comment: What happens if you add `\raggedbottom` to your preamble?

Comment: @Bernard No difference

Comment: @Bernard I'm using the subfile package and see some relationship: It doesn't seem to appear outside of a subfile (i.e. in main)

Comment: @Zarko Please see updated MWE

Comment: @Bernard Please see updated MWE

Comment: Sorry, but we don't know what is in  `\subfile{sub}`, so we can't test your MWE. Also combination of `threeparttable` and `tablefootnotes` is unusual. Removing `subfile{sun}` gives compilable MWE wich works fine.

Comment: @Zarko oops! Was going to fast. It's the exact same content as main, just says inside subfiles instead (and uses the subfiles doc class syntax)

Comment: @Zarko I fixed it (copy and paste error). What is unusual about TPT and tablefootnotes? Is it superfluous? The omission of it does not fix the error.

Comment: @likethevegetable, culprit is in use `subfile`. It cause your problem. As solution can be not use it for inserting a tables on such a way in the main document. Better seems to be using `standalone` package  and `\input{sub}` in the main document, and `\documentclass{standalone}` in `sub` document.

Comment: @likethevegetable, using `standalone` aproach require that for compiling `standalone file you need to load in preamble relevant packages. In your case `\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}`

Comment: It looks okay in texlive which has already subfiles 2020/11/14 v2.2, in miktex there is still subfiles 2020/10/29 v2.1. The author of subfiles asked a few days ago a question to resolve a bug https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570643/2388 and then sent an update to ctan.